# iOS app - macOS username in app bundle

Tags: ios

I track logs from my published to AppStore iOS app.

I noticed that my logs from published app contain my macOS username:

> /Users/**my_macos_username**/Projects/MyApp/MyApp/MyApp_Module/MyApp_class.swift

I get this in logs from `#file` usage. Someone pointed also that username appears in `/Symbols/` directory (probably connected to usage of CocoaPods).

How can I prune my username from app? I don't want to be exposed in any place (logs / ipa metadata / additional resources).

I guess I can change my macOS username to something that I don't mind being exposed, but changing my home directory could be tedious and dangerous for all scripts and projects.

Comment: Use the `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` flags to suppress logging when the app is built for being released.

Comment: Thanks, but I want that logs for recognizing errors from users. 
Also this wouldn't help with username in Pods paths.